# How to handle dynamic changing JSON object in android

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a JSON from an API which returns something this like this -

```
{
 "amount": "10.0000",
 "base_currency_code": "EUR",
 "base_currency_name": "Euro",
   "rates": {
      "GBP": {
       "currency_name": "Pound Sterling",
       "rate": "0.9060",
       "rate_for_amount": "9.0601"
     }
   },
   "status": "success",
   "updated_date": "2020-12-03"
}
```

From the data above, the value of json Object **GBP** changes depending on the currency code selected.

e.g if USD was selected by the user, that will change to **USD**

So, I copied the code and converted the JSON to kotlin data class using a plugin  -

ApiResponse.class

```
data class ApiResponse(
val amount: String,
val base_currency_code: String,
val base_currency_name: String,
val rates: Rates,
val status: String,
val updated_date: String
)

data class Rates(
val GBP: GBP
)

data class GBP(
val currency_name: String,
val rate: String,
val rate_for_amount: String
)
```

As you can see, it generated a static class for the JSON object GBP which changes.

How can I generate my POJO class specifying that the JSON object "GBP" changes based on what is selected.

I am using Retrofit and GSON converter.

Comment: Keep the `GBP` as a `Map<String, String>` .

Answer (score 0):

If You're using `GSON` that's better use `JsonDeserializer<T>` for Custom Parse models.

```java
private class GBPDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<GBP> {

  @Override
  public GBP deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

       //TODO: You should JsonElement convert to JSONObject and by keys()
               method run a dynamically loop and resolve fileds.
 
  }  
}
```